# Disable Microsoft Office Telemetry not working properly. Data Logging Locations very confusing

Tags: windows-10, windows-event-log, microsoft-office, centralized-logging, microsoft-dfo365

Due to the Data Privacy regulations in our Country we have been asked by management to disable Microsoft Office Pro Plus, 365, 2016 from sending Telemetry Data to Microsoft so i did the following as stated on the official website https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/compat/manage-the-privacy-of-data-monitored-by-telemetry-in-office .

So I downloaded ADMX templates > Configuration > Administrative Templates > Microsoft Office 2016 > Telemetry Dashboard and did the following in order to disable Telemetry
Agent policy settings that disable logging

TO STOP LOGGING BY USING THE GROUP POLICY SETTINGS

Setting

**Turn on telemetry data collection**

> Set this setting to Disabled to turn off data collection.

**Turn on data uploading for Office Telemetry Agent**

> Set this setting to Disabled to stop uploading data to the shared folder.

According to Microsoft if logging is deactivated folder this **%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Telemetry**  folder does not exit.
I double checked on one of our test clients and truly that path doesnt exist.

Nevertheless my attention was then drawn to another location **%localappdata%\Microsoft\Office\OTele**. Check out this article [https://www.gruppenrichtlinien.de/artikel/office-20162019365-telemetrie-deaktivieren-disabletelemetry/](http://web.archive.org/web/20190410074605/https://www.gruppenrichtlinien.de/artikel/office-20162019365-telemetrie-deaktivieren-disabletelemetry/)

This location also logs some kind of Office Telemetry Data and it gets populated anytime office is active.
Is this location relevant? If so how do we stop it from logging office Data?

Reference link: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f98dd521-fc45-4187-af30-f00031585f44/disable-microsoft-office-telemetry-not-working-properly-data-logging-locations-very-confusing?forum=Office2016ITPro#f98dd521-fc45-4187-af30-f00031585f44

Comment: I'm also got this mysterious "oTele" folder, despite disabling all telemetry. It contains several pairs of files with the extensions ".db" and ".db.session", one pair for each of several Office applications. Plus ".db-shm" and ".db-wal" in the case of the one Office application (Word) I have open right now. The  .db and .db.session files are all "SQLite format 3" binary files.